# Javascript await/async keywords shows error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, javascript-intellisense

When writing Javascript in a Web application in Visual Studio 2015, the `async` and `await` keywords are marked as error. For example:

```
const response = await fetch(url, options);
```

This is how it looks like in VS2015:

[image: Syntax Errro of await keyword in VS2015]

Here, `await` is marked in red indicating a syntax error. This happens in Javascript files and in `script` elements in html or ASPX pages. All code actually works: I've been succesfully using async/await for a few months so far. The only problem is that  Visual Studio formating/code collapsing fails because of the "error", and always show the annoying red marks.

I tried tweaking some TypeScript options (I even updated Typescript support), but we are using Javascript heavily (migrating to TypeScript is not an option), so it probably wont work anyway.
I found out that I can add "javascript reference files" to visual studio (Options > Javascript > Intellisense), but couldn't find a proper reference to add support for async/await, and probably others newer javascript caracteristicts.

Right now I can't get a newer version of Visual Studio (I'm one of many developers in the same project).

**Additional info**:
This is a web application project (It is an ~8yo project in continuous development). Mostly ASP.NEt + VB.NET, there is a lot of **client side** Javascript (both vanilla and jQuery) executed only in Browser (no NodeJS).

Comment: What is the specific “*error*” VS marks these keywords with? What is the expected execution environment - Node/Electron, browser, some other runtime entirely…?

Comment: The function/object next to `await`  is marked in red. When I hover it, the tool tip only said `expected ";"` (original text is in Spanish: `Se esperaba ';' `)

Comment: VS uses quite outdated version of TS and that's even with VS2019. I uspect VS2015 might use an even older one. I've genuinely not found a better solution other than using a different editor. VS is *not* pleasant to use with TS. It's slow and it does not recognise a lot of common stuff. It's possible that there is a plugin that could be added and/or some configuration to be made to make it recognise newer syntax but I gave up looking for it.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks, thats what I thought, unfortunetilly. We'll be migrating the project to a more recent version of VS ASAP (one reporting tools is preventing us to do so). Bu I want to solve this inconvenient until then.

Comment: I suggest VSCode. Works pretty well. At my work place, we expanded our ReSharper license to also get Rider - it's an alternative to VS for C#. However, it also works really well for writing TS/JS. It's a paid option but might be looking into. I like Rider more than VS. Well, also I've used IntelliJ before and Rider is using the same platform, so I find it familiar but the functionality is also pretty good.